# How to fix "TargetHandler I/O error: General SSLEngine problem"

Tags: wso2, wso2-esb

i have an API in wso2 esb and i am making a https request to an external endpoint, i have imported a certificate as per the documentation using keytool but i still run into the same error

this is how i have imorted my certificate:
keytool -importcert -file  -keystore /repository/resources/security/client-truststore.jks -alias "SomeAlias"

```
[2019-01-02 11:17:06,153] [EI-Core] ERROR - TargetHandler I/O error: General SSLEngine problem javax.net.ssl.SSLHandshakeException: General SSLEngine problem
at sun.security.ssl.Handshaker.checkThrown(Handshaker.java:1529)
at sun.security.ssl.SSLEngineImpl.checkTaskThrown(SSLEngineImpl.java:535)
at sun.security.ssl.SSLEngineImpl.writeAppRecord(SSLEngineImpl.java:1214)
at sun.security.ssl.SSLEngineImpl.wrap(SSLEngineImpl.java:1186)
at javax.net.ssl.SSLEngine.wrap(SSLEngine.java:469)
at org.apache.http.nio.reactor.ssl.SSLIOSession.doWrap(SSLIOSession.java:237)
at org.apache.http.nio.reactor.ssl.SSLIOSession.doHandshake(SSLIOSession.java:271)
at org.apache.http.nio.reactor.ssl.SSLIOSession.isAppInputReady(SSLIOSession.java:410)
at org.apache.http.impl.nio.reactor.AbstractIODispatch.inputReady(AbstractIODispatch.java:119)
at org.apache.http.impl.nio.reactor.BaseIOReactor.readable(BaseIOReactor.java:159)
at org.apache.http.impl.nio.reactor.AbstractIOReactor.processEvent(AbstractIOReactor.java:338)
at org.apache.http.impl.nio.reactor.AbstractIOReactor.processEvents(AbstractIOReactor.java:316)
at org.apache.http.impl.nio.reactor.AbstractIOReactor.execute(AbstractIOReactor.java:277)
at org.apache.http.impl.nio.reactor.BaseIOReactor.execute(BaseIOReactor.java:105)
at org.apache.http.impl.nio.reactor.AbstractMultiworkerIOReactor$Worker.run(AbstractMultiworkerIOReactor.java:586)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
Caused by: javax.net.ssl.SSLHandshakeException: General SSLEngine problem
at sun.security.ssl.Alerts.getSSLException(Alerts.java:192)
at sun.security.ssl.SSLEngineImpl.fatal(SSLEngineImpl.java:1728)
at sun.security.ssl.Handshaker.fatalSE(Handshaker.java:330)
at sun.security.ssl.Handshaker.fatalSE(Handshaker.java:322)
at sun.security.ssl.ClientHandshaker.serverCertificate(ClientHandshaker.java:1614)
at sun.security.ssl.ClientHandshaker.processMessage(ClientHandshaker.java:216)
at sun.security.ssl.Handshaker.processLoop(Handshaker.java:1052)
at sun.security.ssl.Handshaker$1.run(Handshaker.java:992)
at sun.security.ssl.Handshaker$1.run(Handshaker.java:989)
at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
at sun.security.ssl.Handshaker$DelegatedTask.run(Handshaker.java:1467)
at org.apache.http.nio.reactor.ssl.SSLIOSession.doRunTask(SSLIOSession.java:255)
at org.apache.http.nio.reactor.ssl.SSLIOSession.doHandshake(SSLIOSession.java:293)
... 9 more
Caused by: sun.security.validator.ValidatorException: PKIX path building failed: sun.security.provider.certpath.SunCertPathBuilderException: unable to find valid certification path to requested target
at sun.security.validator.PKIXValidator.doBuild(PKIXValidator.java:397)
at sun.security.validator.PKIXValidator.engineValidate(PKIXValidator.java:302)
at sun.security.validator.Validator.validate(Validator.java:260)
at sun.security.ssl.X509TrustManagerImpl.validate(X509TrustManagerImpl.java:324)
at sun.security.ssl.X509TrustManagerImpl.checkTrusted(X509TrustManagerImpl.java:281)
at sun.security.ssl.X509TrustManagerImpl.checkServerTrusted(X509TrustManagerImpl.java:136)
at sun.security.ssl.ClientHandshaker.serverCertificate(ClientHandshaker.java:1601)
... 17 more
```

Caused by: sun.security.provider.certpath.SunCertPathBuilderException: unable to find valid certification path to requested target
    at sun.security.provider.certpath.SunCertPathBuilder.build(SunCertPathBuilder.java:141)
    at sun.security.provider.certpath.SunCertPathBuilder.engineBuild(SunCertPathBuilder.java:126)
    at java.security.cert.CertPathBuilder.build(CertPathBuilder.java:280)
    at sun.security.validator.PKIXValidator.doBuild(PKIXValidator.java:392)

Comment: Did you restart the server after importing? plz provide the full error.

Comment: yes i did restart the server

Comment: @Bee i have put the whole error now

Comment: this should be fixed if you import the correct cert. plz double check.

Comment: i have even tried with a different cert, but the same problem persists, checked and confirmed that all is okay

Comment: one possibility is that it can need a certificate chain.

Comment: @Bee how do i go about that?

Comment: Can you attach the installed cert and show me the backend url?

Comment: @Bee i am not allowed to do that, but the backend url is in form of iP i.e https://104.xx.xx.xx